# Java LWJGL custom texture

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm working on a smallish game with a friend and we ran into a really annoying problem with sprite sheets and textures... Right now we're just using Slick2D's textureloader and we even tried their SpriteSheet but no luck. What we really need is just a custom textureloader or whatever you may call it to load a big texture, break it into smaller textures, and save the new smaller textures into maybe an array. If you know a site that could help or maybe just paste your code that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had fine luck with the code below in [one of my projects](https://github.com/normalocity/pedestrians/blob/master/src/com/jefflunt/pedestrians/PedestrianSim.java). I happen to keep textures in individual files, but it seems to work without issue.

If you want to load one big image, you can do that the same way, and then chop it up into pieces using the [subImage method](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#getSubImage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) of the [Image class](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html). Just note that the documentation mentions that, any sub-image "retains a reference to the [original] image data, so should anything change [in the parent image] it will affect sub-images too."

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;

...whatever code you've got...

/** Loads the image resources needed for the game.
*
* @throws SlickException if there is a problem loading one of the images
*/
public void loadImageResources() throws SlickException {
  images = new Image[6];

  images[0] = new Image("images/controls/play.png");
  images[1] = new Image("images/controls/pause.png");
  images[2] = new Image("images/tiles/stone.png");
  images[3] = new Image("images/peds/ped.png");
  images[4] = new Image("images/peds/ped_add.png");
  images[5] = new Image("images/peds/ped_remove.png");
}
```

Comment: Sweet! but one question, how would I convert the Images into textures for OPenGL?

Comment: Ah, well I can't help you there, but if you're using Slick2D you aren't supposed to have to touch OpenGL - Slick2D manages that for you. Is there a specific reason you're digging down into OpenGL? If so, is Slick2D the right library for you (i.e. are you writing your entire game in Slick2D)?

Comment: Yea I'm currently using Slick2D for their pre-made Texture and TextureLoader, eventually I wanted to have my code running off of lwjgl alone, I'm kinda a noob at this so I followed their tutorial on loading images into the display and they said to use Slick2D for that so I did but being on two sources limit your capabilities a little